# How do I write this MySQL query?

Tags: sql, database-design, mysql

I am working on an Asset DB using a lamp stack.

In this example consider the following 5 tables:

asset,
server,
laptop,
desktop,
software

All tables have a primary key of id, which is a unique asset id.

Every object has all asset attributes and then depending on type of asset has additional attributes in the corresponding table.  If the type is a server, desktop or laptop it also has items in the software table.

Here are the table create statements:

```
// connect to mysql server and database "asset_db"
mysql_connect("localhost", "asset_db", "asset_db") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("asset_db") or die(mysql_error());

// create asset table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE asset(
id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
company VARCHAR(50), 
location VARCHAR(50),
purchase_date VARCHAR(50),
purchase_order VARCHAR(50),
value VARCHAR(50),
type VARCHAR(50),
notes VARCHAR(200))")
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Asset Table Created.</br />";

// create software table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE software(
id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
software VARCHAR(50),
license VARCHAR(50))")
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Software Table Created.</br />";

// create laptop table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE laptop(
id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
manufacturer VARCHAR(50),
model VARCHAR(50),
serial_number VARCHAR(50),
esc VARCHAR(50),
user VARCHAR(50),
prev_user VARCHAR(50),
warranty VARCHAR(50))")
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Laptop Table Created.</br />";

// create desktop table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE desktop(
id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
manufacturer VARCHAR(50),
model VARCHAR(50),
serial_number VARCHAR(50),
esc VARCHAR(50),
user VARCHAR(50),
prev_user VARCHAR(50),
warranty VARCHAR(50))")
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Desktop Table Created.</br />";

// create server table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE server(
id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
manufacturer VARCHAR(50), 
model VARCHAR(50),
warranty VARCHAR(50))")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Server Table Created.</br />";

?>
```

How do I query the database so that if I search by id, I receive all related fields to that asset id?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT asset.id
    ,asset.company
    ,asset.location
    -- ,... Any more columns from asset
    ,software.software
    ,software.license
    ,laptop.model AS laptop_model
    ,desktop.model AS desktop_model
    -- etc.
    ,COALESCE(laptop.model, server.model, desktop.model) AS model -- assumes only one non-NULL
FROM asset
LEFT JOIN software
    ON software.id = asset.id
LEFT JOIN laptop
    ON laptop.id = asset.id
LEFT JOIN desktop
    ON desktop.id = asset.id
LEFT JOIN server
    ON server.id = asset.id
WHERE asset.id = <your_id>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am a little confused on the AS laptop_model and AS desktop_model.  Could you elaborate?  Sorry new to this...

Comment: @CT If you have columns with identical names, it is common to alias them to make them unambiguous.  In some data access environments, it is also difficult to extract the correct column if you have multiple columns with the same name in a rowset.